# How do I confine a boids particle system to a volume?

Tags: particles, physics

Is there a way to have boid particles be generally confined to a volume? For example, if I were to make a fish tank or fish net, and would want schooling fish to be animated throughout but wanted them to stay within the confines of the volume, is there a way to tell them to flock, but do not exit the volume?

I'm trying to figure a way to make a large school of fish remain in the background of a shot without letting them go all over the place. I've tried having them follow the leader and having the leader move, but it sprays fish across the camera view and all over. Once they start to flock, they just end up spiraling in a cylinder type thing. I'd ideally have them be in a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Just use avoid/avoid collision for your surrounding box. Of course you need the right values to make it work. And AFAIK there is no thing like "stay in that volume" for boids.